# Exception,without handling,code running well. ClassnotfondException

Tags: java, exception, classnotfoundexception

```
try{
   if((Boolean)ppb.getParameters().get("abc")){
     Sysout.print("if true it goes inside else continue the code below");
    }
     System.out.print("if classcastexception print this")
 }catch{
    System.out.print("classcastexception but neverprint out");
 }
```

When I start the debug mode(Eclipse), the code keep running well, 
  even there is a try catch block, but never go inside the block.
  But when I use `CNTRL-SHIFT-I` to check the value of 
  `(Boolean)ppb.getParameters().get("abc")`, it says "ClassCastException".

So here are my questions:

1. When the value of `ppb.getParameters().get("abc")`  is a String type, casting it to Boolean throws a exception.  But why does it keep running?  Why does it never go into the try 
   catch block?
2. Since it running well without interruption, should I handle this exception 
   or not?

Comment: Hello, welcome to StackOverflow. You should edit your post to add the tag of the programming language you're using. This will help people to find your question.

Comment: And please (next time!) try to use proper spelling, punctuation and spelling, and try to use correct Markdown to format your questions to be readable.  I have fixed ... the mess.